# Discord.py How can I make a bot delete messages after a specific amount of time

Tags: python, discord

I have a discord bot that sends images to users when they use the !img command, I don't want people to request an image and then have it sit there until someone deletes it. Is there any way I can make it delete images after 10 seconds or so without using any blocking functions such as `time.sleep()` in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Messageable.send` has a `delete_after` kwarg that takes the amount of seconds to delete the sent message after, for example

```py
await channel.send("this message will be deleted after 10 seconds", delete_after=10)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send